# Efficient way to validate xml?

Tags: c#, xml

I need to validate as fast as possible and receive the next xml-data on socket.

I am using this method to validate received xml-datas.

```
private validateRecievedXmlCallback()
{
  try
  {      
    XmlReader xreader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlData));
    while (xreader.Read()) ;
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

But I think this method is not efficient enought. I actually need to check the last tag only.

example:

```
<test valueA="1" valueB="2">
   <data valueC="1" />
   <data valueC="5" />
   <data valueC="5">220</data>
</test>  //I need to check if </test> tag closed, but whats the best way to do it?
```

Comment: So, let me see … You need to check for the presence of `</test>` in a string, right?

Comment: yes, but i dont want to use substring, because it can happen <test valueA="1" valueB="2" />

Comment: Why down vote? This is just a question?

Comment: Downvote without a comment? Thank You.

Comment: @VuralAcar I upvoted you

Comment: What are your "fast" and "efficient" concerns? As searching for a closing tag seems like a band-aid solution.

Comment: One stupid question, if I may (as I do not know anything about C#): How does `ar` magically become `xmlData`? Also, @Kane: You're *absolutely* right.

Comment: You actually used "efficient" and "XML" in the same sentence?!?

Comment: well, its not a good idea to check the last tag only.

Comment: @VuralAcar, Do you handle the cases where you may receive 2 (even 2.5) xml in one chunk?

Comment: Yes but the server sends the xml-datas so fast, some times i am getting problem reading and validating them. example (1,5xml) before I validate it, I recieve ((1,5xml)+(1xml)) and its no more valid..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you stick with the XmlReader, you could use XmlReader.Skip() which, well, skips the content of the current element.

So

```
xreader.ReadStartElement("test"); // moves to document root, throws if it is not <test>
xreader.Skip(); // throws if document is not well-formed, e.g. root has no closing tag.
```

As other commenters have stated already, there is no good way of guaranteeing well-formedness of a XML document except for using a XML parser.

Answer (score 1):

**Anyone actually facing the same challenge as the OP: Refer to [the answer by Sven Künzler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8886877/961510) and never think about building your own XML "validation" again.**

---

**Edit:** Added self-closing tag regex check.

**Edit2:** Made regex actually do what it's supposed to

**Edit3:** Edit double-closed tag check (hat tip to *RichardW1001*)

```
private validateRecievedXmlCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    string sPattern = @"^<test([^>]*) \/>$";
    if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(xmlData, sPattern))
    {
        return(true);
    }

    int first_occurence = xmlData.IndexOf("</test>");
    int last_occurence  = xmlData.LastIndexOf("</test>");
    return((first_occurence != -1) && (first_occurence == last_occurence));
}
```

**Disclaimer:** It is generally a stupid idea to try and "validate" XML by means of regex, `IndexOf()` or any other "homegrown" methods. Just use a proper XML parser.

Comment: Thank you, Xml parser is reading every line, but i dont need to validate each attribute or element. I only need to know if its complated or not.

Comment: This is why you have your disclaimer, but what about if the end tag is double-closed?

Comment: @RichardW1001 Uhm … I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by "double-closed". Would you care to provide an example?

Comment: I know the moral of the story is to just use a proper parser, guess it's down to original poster whether it matters or not (not specified in question)

Comment: @RichardW1001 Fixed, thanks (Also, I hope what I produced looks at least a little like C#).